# Plupload - trigger event before FilesRemoved

Tags: jquery, events, file-upload, plupload

I'm working on plupload plugin and i need to do something before `FilesRemoved` event. for example i want to check some condition and if condition was not ok, prevent from removing file. in fact, i want to disable removing file from queue for some conditions. i tried this code, but not worked:

```
$("#uploader").plupload({
    init: {
       FilesRemoved: function (){
          if(/*condition was not ok*/)
              return false;
       },


       //some other events
     }


 //other plupload settins
});
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://www.plupload.com/docs/Uploader#Init-event) `FilesRemoved` fires when file is removed from the queue. So this event does not help you because it's an event after removal.

Maybe `QueueChanged` event is a good choice for you which fires when the file queue is changed. In other words when files are added/removed to the files array of the uploader instance.

I don't know what you want to do in the condition statement. Maybe knowing that would help. Any way, the link I mentioned provides all the events which you can choose from based on your business logic.

Comment: i need to send file id via ajax request and delete a record from database and if this process was not successful, be prevented from deleting file.

Comment: In which event you are trying to delete the record from database and would inform about the errors?